# Rosyln.SDK missing from Visual Studio layout

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, roslyn

I'm creating an offline [network installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for VS2019, combined with VS [config export/import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2019) to mirror my VS install between two machines.
I've selected specific workflows to reduce the layout from 50->15ish GB but when trying to install I get:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me see where this comes from.

- It is *not* listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-professional?view=vs-2019
- It is *not* included in my exported vsconfig file:

> {   "version": "1.0",   "components": [
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.5.0",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp",
> "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.ClickOnce.Publish",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Web",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.4.3",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics",
> "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
> "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.RazorExtension",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.ADAL",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSSQL.CMDLnUtils",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources",
> "Component.Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager",
> "Component.Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.WebLivePreview",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.1.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.TargetingPack",
> "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common",
> "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Compute.Emulator",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.Emulator",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ClientLibs",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.AuthoringTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
> "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WslDebugging",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
> "Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.2.1",
> "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041",
> "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.PythonTools.NativeDevelopment",
> "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Miniconda",
> "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Web",
> "Component.CPython39.x64",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Node.Tools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites",
> "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.MSIX.Packaging",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
> "Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Support",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal",
> "Microsoft.Component.CodeAnalysis.SDK",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Git",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools.2.1",
> "Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web.2.1"   ] }

- I *can* see it exists in a full layout and doesn't in my custom layout but not which workflow it comes from. Or why it hasn't automatically been added, isn't this a core component?
- When I try to `--add Roslyn.SDK` to my layout using the VS installer I get the error **Error: The package 'Roslyn.SDK' is not recognized.**

So where does it come from and how can I get it in a custom layout? Can I even hack it into my layout somehow?

How can I find which workflow/component to add to get this included?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that Rosyln.SDK is used by several workloads, as a non-documented dependency. Such as:

> Visual Studio extension development ID:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension Description:
> Create add-ons and extensions for Visual Studio, including new
> commands, code analyzers and tool windows.

ADding this resolves the issues I have but leaves me thinking it should have been there already for C#/.Net development.